# Align right kanban view Odoo

Tags: html, button, odoo, text-align

I am trying to align to the right of the kanban box the "Edit" tag which displays the form view.
I have tried by manually specifying text-align:right, primary_left, primary_right ...

Nothing have worked yet.
Do you know how can I separate the name and the edit button so the edit button stays aligned to the right of the box?

[image]

[image: code]

Comment: Try to use `float-right text-right` classes.

Comment: @kenly Thank you so much. The combination of float-right and text-right, did the trick. I tried both separately but didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `style` attribute with value `text-align:right` .

For example,

> <a style="text-align:right;" modifiers="{}" ...... />

Comment: Thats not working. I added that to my code ad still the same :(